# How to solve $1+2^{a}+2^{2a+1}=b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to find all integer solutions for $1+2^{a}+2^{2a+1}=b^2$. How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. When $a\le -1$, $1<1+2^a+2^{2a+1}\le 2$, no solution.
2. When $a=0$, $b=\pm 2$.
3. When $a\ge 1$, from
   $$(2^a+1)^2<b^2=1+2^a+2^{2a+1}<(2^a+2^{a-1}+1)^2$$
   we know that $|b|=2^a+k$ for some integer $k$ satisfying $2\le k\le 2^{a-1}$. 
   Since
   $$1+2^a+2^{2a+1}=(2^a+k)^2\Rightarrow 2^a\mid (k-1)(k+1)$$
   and since $\gcd(k-1, k+1)\le 2$, we know that either $2^{a-1}\mid (k-1)$ or $2^{a-1}\mid (k+1)$. However, since $2\le k\le 2^{a-1}$, the only possible case is $k=2^{a-1}-1$. 
   Then
   $$1+2^a+2^{2a+1}=(2^a+2^{a-1}-1)^2\iff a=4.$$
   Therefore, when $a\ge 1$, $a=4$ and $b=\pm 23$.

Comment: $1<1+2^a+2^{2a+1}\leq 2$ does not imply, that there are no solutions. In fact there is one in this case (actually two).

Comment: @Tomas: There is no integer $b$, such that $1<b^2\le 2$.

Comment: Oops, I apologize.

Comment: @Tomas: Never mind.

Comment: Isn't there another possible $k$, $k=1$? That gets elimininated - $k=1$ implies $a=0$. But it is certainly a possible case.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Yes, you are right. Thank you for reminding. I have edited my answer accordingly.